# Couldn't select proper close-question reason

Tags: bug

Ref: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155366/words-and-reading-level#155382

I put close... not on topic... belongs on other site.  The only "other site" listed was meta.english.  I would expect either a list of all sites or a freeform text field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug. This is "by design" so that users can't just send questions here and there with nary a care.

For example, we used to be able to migrate from EL&U to Writers. However, that caused problems because many EL&U users don't actually know what goes on at Writers, so bad migrations happened and that path was closed to us.

Paths for migration by us normal users must be opened by the Stack Exchange team. This doesn't happen very often.

If you want to recommend that a question be migrated to a site not in the currently approved list you can flag it with "other (needs ♦ moderator attention)" and specify where and why.

Comment: Thanks!  And that's exactly what I did with the user's next question.

Comment: One thought on this... I appreciate your quick response and marking correct since you obviously know the history.  But I'm not sure that "not a bug; by design" is the best way to describe this. I'm sure it's not by design that I'm led down an illogical path. Perhaps a another way to answer would be *something along the lines of* "This is a known issue which had to be worked around by removing the other site options. Given the workaround, it's a low priority issue now... you can alternatively...".

Comment: @CoolHandLouis: Yes, it is by design that users cannot select where a question should be asked, as Matt said. If you dislike the design feature it should probably be raised at meta.stackoverflow, but if flagging works just as well for you and better for the design team and the mods on other sites (as appears to be the case) calling it a bug is itself illogical.

Comment: @TimLymington My suggestion is both logical and thoughtful. I have no problem at all with the fixed issue design/implementation. It's a complex platform that requires issues to be addressed according to priority, cost, resources, etc. The issue described has been fixed and the status is "Resolved Closed" or some such, and so Matt/SoftwareDevs/WhoeverOpensTickets has no need to open a new bug or design issue ticket for this. Therefore, from a systems view, it is considered neither a bug nor a design issue at this time.